# Unity. 2D коллайдер объекта, перекрывает другой коллайдер, находящийся над ним

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть объект `Card`, который я могу перетащить на другой объект `Hand`. `Hand` и `Card` обладают 2D коллайдерами. `Order in Layer` у `Card` выше, чем у `Hand` и она отображается сверху, но при этом ее коллайдер перестает каким-либо образом регестрировать наведение мышью. Если карта не находится внутри коллайдера `Hand` все работает отлично. Каким образом это можно исправить?
[image: Компоненты карты]

[image: Компоненты руки]

Comment: Каким образом  какой-то там порядок в каких-то там слоях вообще должен хоть как-то влиять на физику? Зачем физика в карточной игре тоже отдельный вопрос, не можешь посчитать находится ли курсор в прямоугольнике?

Comment: @Yaroslav Я новичок и возможно мои вопросы кажутся очень глупыми, но для меня они являются большой проблемой, поэтому я и задаю их здесь.

Comment: `Order in Layer` это параметр `Renderer`, то есть отрисовки, никакого отношения к чему-либо другому это не относится и ни на что другое не влияет, совсем. Читаем документацию, там написан функционал всех компонентов и всех их параметров и не придётся придумывать того, чего нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как 2D физика это подмножество 3D физики, то для 2D действуют такая же логика как и для обычной физики. Есть некоторые ограничения выведенные из требований что Z(глубина) не имеет значения для отрисовки и все лучи исходящие от камеры являются параллельными оси Z.

Судя из описания проблемы, из физики используется колайдеры и event system с Raycast2D, которые выполняют запросы к физике(Raycast) в физическую сцену для того чтобы получить объект который находится под мышкой или нажатием и отправить ему сообщение об этом.

Т.к. ваши объекты на сцене имеют одинаковые координаты Z - они вступают в гонку "кто будет первым в списке на проверку на пересечение с лучем" и только один из них выигрывает ее условно-случайном образом(например один выше в иерархии сцены, или позже создавался).

Решение - управлять порядком через контролирование Z координаты. Тот кто имеет ближе к 0 значение тот и будет блокировать отстальных.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена. Нужно просто было изменить координату Z у `Hand` так, чтобы она находилась дальше от камеры, чем `Card`

Comment: Очередной баг повержен. Так держать!

Comment: Можно просто отключить коллайдер у руки, когда в ней что-то, в этом случае по ней в принципе нельзя кликнуть, только по тому что в ней.